# Twice cross domain

Tags: php, html, cross-domain, cas

I want to access data from cross domain in website frontend. 
I have three websites: a.com, b.com and c.com. The site a.com is frontend. The site b.com is backend(API). The c.com is CAS server.

I can directly access the http://b.com/example_test.php on browser. It successfully jump to CAS page to login. Then after login, API returns data.

I want to let a.com to get b.com's data. My code is:

My frontend html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3 id="article_title"></h3>
    <p id="article_text"></p>
    </body>

    <script type="application/javascript">
      var xmlHttpReq = null;
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }

      if (xmlHttpReq !== null) {
        xmlHttpReq.open("get", "http://b.com/example_test.php");
        xmlHttpReq.timeout = 10000;
        xmlHttpReq.send("");
        xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = doResult;
      }

      function doResult() {    
        if (xmlHttpReq.readyState === 4) {
          console.log(xmlHttpReq.status);
          if (xmlHttpReq.status === 200) {
            var data = xmlHttpReq.responseText;
            var json_data = JSON.parse(data);
            /**
             do somethin.
             */
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
    </html>
```

My backend api example_test.php:

```
    <?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,HEAD,OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin,Content-Type,Authorization,X-auth-Token');
    require_once './MyCAS.php';

    $resp = array(
        'stats' => -1,
        'msg' => 'Empty!'
    );
    if (array_key_exists('username', $_COOKIE)) {
        /**
         do something
         **/
    } else {
        phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, "mycase.server.com", 443, "/cas", false);
        phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();
        phpCAS::forceAuthentication();
        if (phpCAS::isAuthenticated()) {
            $username = phpCAS::getUser();
            if ($username !== null) {
                $token = md5($username.date('s', time()).date('i', time()));
                setcookie('username', $username, time() + 1*86400, '/');
                setcookie('token', $token, time() + 1*86400, '/');

                /**
                 do something
                 **/
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

But when I access a.com on browser, I it does not jumps to CAS page. I don't understand the problem. Can any one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you check ajax loading in your browser network and what is the response sent by it.

Comment: @Rohit.007 I access a.com, browser received cas server's page content and code is 200, But it don't jump.

Comment: By Jump, you mean it does not redirect on cas server's page?

Comment: @Rohit.007 Yes, the browser console can find page content, preview is page, but not jump. It is strange.

Comment: @Rohit.007 You can try my code. You can replace cas server code to header('Location: your c.com');

Comment: Ajax calls does not redirects the page. Either you need to send a flag with it and on the HTML page make a javascript location redirect.

Comment: @Rohit.007 How do I send flag?

Comment: Send json encoded response and on the basis of it make a document.location.href change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not redirect the caller's request by ajax. One way to achieve it with JavaScript.

PHP example:

```
<?php
echo 'redirect';
```

On you HTML JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url: '/users',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                if(data == 'redirect'){
                    console.log(jqXHR.status);
                    window.location.href= "/thankyou.html";
                }
            }
        });
```